# How can I reach this set of TR tags?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is the link to the actual HTML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&fstype=iii'))
```

And an approximate HTML snippet:

```
<div id="incannualdiv">
  <table id="fs-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>..</tr>
      ...
      <tr>
        <td>Net Income</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

These are the details I'm working with:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&fstype=iii'))
div = doc.at "div[@id='incannualdiv']" #div containing the table i want
table = div.at 'table' #table containing tbody i want
tbody = table.at 'tbody' #tbody containing tr's I want
trs = tbody.at 'tr' #SHOULD be all tr's of that table/tbody - but it's only the first TR?
```

I expect that last bit to give me ALL the `<TR>` tags, which would include the `<TD>` I'm looking for, but in fact it only gives me the first `<TR>`.

Here's the next piece:

```
irb(main):023:0> a = nil
=> nil
irb(main):024:0> doc.css('#incannualdiv > #fs-table tr').each { |e| if e.text.include? "Net Income\n"; a = e.text; end}
=> 0
irb(main):025:0> a
=> "Net Income\n\n191.00\n611.00\n254.00\n-1,151.00\n"
irb(main):026:0> a.split"\n"
=> ["Net Income", "", "191.00", "611.00", "254.00", "-1,151.00"]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also updated your HTML sample. "Net Income\n\n191.00\n611.00\n254.00\n-1,151.00\n" is not reflected in it.

Comment: Nevermind, I just followed the link. You only want the "Net Income", not the other "Net Income..."s right?

Comment: yeah exactly, you got it. sorry for the crappy html sample, but the real html is...well...complicated. +1's for the help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
doc.css('#incannualdiv > #fs-table tr')
```

`at_css` (and I guess `at`) returns one element where `css` returns all matching.

**Edit**: Answer to OP's Comment

You can get the text in the `tr` which is actually the text in its children `td`s by using the `text` method

```
trs = doc.css('#incannualdiv > #fs-table tr')
# Get column labels from table headers
labels = trs.first.css('th')[1..-1].map(&:text)
net_income_tr = trs.detect { |tr|
  tr.css('td').any? { |td| td.text.strip =~ /^Net Income$/ }
}
# drop first tr that just has Net Income text
# I gave up on error checking. Exercise left to reader ;)
# this will give you an array of floats for your Net Income columns
net_income_columns = net_income_tr.css('td')[1..-1].map { |td| td.text.gsub(',','_').to_f }

labeled_values = net_income_columns.each_with_index.map { |value, i| { label: labels[i].strip, value: value } }
```

Comment: ugh, sorry to do this to you but there's more here - I need to get a particular set of TD's inside one of the TR's returned here. That set of TD's is identified by the text of the first TD being equal to "Net Income"

Comment: I know this changes the question a bit but i keep getting this close and can't figure out the next step.

Comment: I added an update to respond to your comment. I think I got it right.

Comment: well, very close, but i think that returns to much. some of the TD's contain "Net Income" but are variations. Like "Net Income Before Extra Items".

Comment: check out my updated OP. this is where I got last time, too. it's the a.split part that i'm trying to get around. I assume there's a cleaner way